# MP3 player mpman TS300 not recognized

Tags: drivers, mp3-player

I just received a mpman ts300 mp3 player for Christmas. But when I try to connect it to ubuntu (10.10) through usb it doesn't seem to be recognized.
I searched for a linuxdriver but came up with nothing. I even tried installing mpman manager from the software center, but still the same problem...
Has anybody got any ideas about how to fix this?
Thank you

edit: some additional information

When I plug it in, it doesn't show up under /dev. And it is not listed in the result of 'lsusb'

This is the output of 'dmesg'

`[19571.732541] usb 1-4: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2

[19571.889154] scsi7 : usb-storage 1-4:1.0

[19572.883155] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TS300    USB DISK         1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0

[19572.885856] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0

[19572.887266] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 7868416 512-byte logical blocks: (4.02 GB/3.75 GiB)

[19573.012547] usb 1-4: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2

[19573.292550] usb 1-4: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2

[19573.572565] usb 1-4: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2

[19573.725019] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled

[19573.725024] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through

[19573.728521] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk

[19575.333015] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 7868416 512-byte logical blocks: (4.02 GB/3.75 GiB)

[19575.452547] usb 1-4: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2

[19580.603253] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/all, error -110

[19580.722560] usb 1-4: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2

[19595.842579] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[19611.072656] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[19611.302540] usb 1-4: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2

[19616.332568] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/8, error -110

[19621.462692] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/8, error -110

[19621.692551] usb 1-4: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2

[19626.722567] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/8, error -110

[19631.852802] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/8, error -110

[19631.962587] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, address 2

[19631.962587] sd 7:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery

[19631.962840] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through

[19631.965104] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] READ CAPACITY failed

[19631.965109] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK

[19631.965112] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.

[19631.965125] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through

[19631.965130] sdb: detected capacity change from 4028628992 to 0

[19632.130042] usb 1-4: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3

[19647.242550] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[19662.472560] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[19662.702566] usb 1-4: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4

[19677.822587] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[19693.052575] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[19693.282582] usb 1-4: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 5

[19698.312600] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/8, error -110

[19703.442594] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/8, error -110

[19703.672548] usb 1-4: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 6

[19708.702581] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/8, error -110

[19713.840077] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/8, error -110

[19713.942555] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 4

[19714.262545] usb 4-2: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 2

[19729.382549] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[19744.612534] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[19744.842543] usb 4-2: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 3

[19759.962714] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[19775.200047] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[19775.422630] usb 4-2: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 4

[19780.444498] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110

[19785.574491] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110

[19785.802547] usb 4-2: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 5

[19790.824490] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110

[19795.961473] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110

[19796.062556] hub 4-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2`

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am voting to close it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Nick. Are you still facing the problem? I stumbled upon your question when searching for some solution for exactly the same problem, but with a Sony Ericsson W580i.

Well, it happens I found this page on http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-797789.html and there are some hints that seem to work there. The first one did the job for me. Not immediately, but it took about 60 seconds for Ubuntu to tell me I got a "wired network disconnected" (probably usb0, as I could see later in syslog).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting a **lot** of errors. Try a different cable and/or a different USB port on your computer. If you're plugging into a hub...try a direct-to-computer connection.

Comment: I already tried using a different USB port. It's not plugged into a hub.
I have to use the default cable that comes with the package. But I know it's not broken, because it works perfectly on a windows installation. :-/

Comment: Do you need special software to use the device under Windows?

Comment: It comes with it's own software, yes.
But I can also use it without, like any other removable drive.

Comment: The Sansa series of players tries this crazy "autodetect" routine which usually fails under Ubuntu (because Ubuntu will support MTP-only players). Is there a setting on the device to force use of USB Mass Storage?

Comment: There's no setting to force Mass Storage. I can only connect the USB cable, and it automatically enters USB-mode. (most likely the autodetect routine)